# Parsing HTML with PHP using DomDocument

Tags: php

Ok so I would like to parse HTML from a site (any site so I do not know the IDs or anything) and if they have the keyword in their content to return that link. I have used the cURL library to retrieve a site but after trying to parse it I have failed many times.

I am a bit lost so thank you for your time! I just get a blank webpage so clearly it's a mistake.

This is the code I am using with this website as an example

```
$b = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask';

$cSession = curl_init(); 

curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_URL, $b);
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 

$result=curl_exec($cSession);

curl_close($cSession);

$dom = new domDocument;
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

$dom->loadHTML($result);

if (strpos($dom,'HTML') === true) {
echo $b;
```

Comment: `strpos()` will *never* return TRUE, therefore your *echo* statement doesn't get executed.

Comment: Thank you! I had tried using !==false but then it didn't seem to be working either

Comment: @user2350696 You should use === false as e.g 0 could be false...

Comment: thanks! I am using what you have recommended now but when I search the $dom for the key word, it seems to never echo "Not found" regardless of what keyword I put in. It now always just echos my link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ComFreek says, strpos does not return true. It returns false on failure, but never true. Instead, check if strpos returns false like this:

```
if (strpos($dom,'HTML') === FALSE) {
 echo "Not found";
}else{
 echo $b;
}
```

EDIT:

try this instead!

```
$b = 'www.sponsored.dk';

$cSession = curl_init(); 

curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_URL, $b);
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 

$result=curl_exec($cSession);

curl_close($cSession);


if (strpos($result,'body') === false) {
echo "Not found";
}else{
echo $b;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation and now everything is working! Many thanks

Comment: Although now it never says 'Not found' even when the keyword is not there. It always seem to display the link! Not sure why

Comment: Sorry, i just edited, try the code, and see if it does what you want

Comment: And now it works perfectly! Can't thank you enough. Not sure why I thought I needed DOMDocument at all.

Comment: It depends on how advanced you wanna go. Basicly DOMDocument makes it represent the HTML document, and you can use the buildt in functions such as getElementById and such, but for your use, that should do just fine..
Remember setting the question as answered so people know :)